# Visual Studio Project doesn't load after changing folder name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a Visual Studio C# solution which consists of some projects. I needed to change the name of one of them and after the namespaces and classes refactoring I had to also change the folder name. After I did that, the project stopped loading inside of the solution. How can I make it load again?

Comment: Did you update the path in the solution file itself to reflect the folder change?

Comment: Remove the project from the solution and re-add it. I assume you didn't update the path to the project file in the solution file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit your csproj/sln file in a text editor and fix the folder name there as well. VS can have issues when you change the project file name.

Just make sure the path matches anywhere you see a path and it should fix it.

Also when a project is unloaded, you can double click on it to open the .csproj file! Then just try to reload when you think you have the values changed correctly.

Comment: It's the .sln that always contains the folder names, I believe. Worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Solved this one for me too